# Can someone help me with return functions?

Tags: java, function

I'm a really beginner to coding. For school, I need to create an "online store" where users can add, remove, view order, or checkout. I created return functions for add and remove since I have to return the updated "cart" after adding or removing an item. Here's the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arr[] = new int[5]; 
    int task, Item, Add, Remove;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Ye Old Shoppe!\nWe sell items at the lowest price in town!\nDue to prices being so low, we sell only 5 items\nevery day and the items change every day!");
    System.out.println("For today, we are selling:");

    System.out.println("\n1. Add Items\n2. Remove Items\n3. View Order\n4. Checkout");
    System.out.print("> ");
    task = key.nextInt();

    if(task == 1){
        System.out.println("\nWhich item do you want to add?");
        System.out.println("\n1. Premium fidget spinners($25)\n2. Nintendo Switch($295)\n3. Handmade leather wallet($65)\n4. 2 packages of A4 paper($50)\n5. Bluetooth Earbuds($40)");
        System.out.print("> ");
        Item = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nHow many?");
        System.out.print("> ");
        Add = key.nextInt();
        addItems(arr, Item, Add);
    }else if(task == 2){
        System.out.println("\nWhich item do you want to remove?");
        System.out.println("\n1. Premium fidget spinners($25)\n2. Nintendo Switch($295)\n3. Handmade leather wallet($65)\n4. 2 packages of A4 paper($50)\n5. Bluetooth Earbuds($40)");
        System.out.print("> ");
        Item = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\nHow many?");
        System.out.print("> ");
        Remove = key.nextInt();
        removeItems(arr, Item, Remove);
    }else if(task == 3){
        viewOrder(arr);
    }
}
public static int[] addItems(int[] cart, int item, int addNum){
    if(item == 1){
        while(item > 0 && item < 6 && addNum > 0 && addNum < 6){
            for(int i = 0; i < addNum; i++){
                cart = ArrayUtils.add(cart,1);
                return cart;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid chocie");
    }else if(item == 2){
        while(item > 0 && item < 6 && addNum > 0 && addNum < 6){
            for(int i = 0; i < addNum; i++){
                cart = ArrayUtils.add(cart,1);
                return cart;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid chocie");
    }else if(item == 3){
        while(item > 0 && item < 6 && addNum > 0 && addNum < 6){
            for(int i = 0; i < addNum; i++){
                cart = ArrayUtils.add(cart,1);
                return cart;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid chocie");
    }else if(item == 4){
        while(item > 0 && item < 6 && addNum > 0 && addNum < 6){
            for(int i = 0; i < addNum; i++){
                cart = ArrayUtils.add(cart,1);
                return cart;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid chocie");
    }else if(item == 5){
        while(item > 0 && item < 6 && addNum > 0 && addNum < 6){
            for(int i = 0; i < addNum; i++){
                cart = ArrayUtils.add(cart,1);
                return cart;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid chocie");
    }
    return cart;
}
```

After adding my item to the cart, I want to return to the main menu in the main method where the program asks me again if I want to add, remove, view order, or checkout. How do I do this??

Comment: this has nothing to do with returning. You already return it. Now, you need to assign the returned value to a variable in your main method, and put a loop in your main method, that repeats as long as you don't chose 'quit'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I'm returning an array and.. which loop are you talking about?? Sorry i'm like a really really beginner

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  You are already returning.  What are you actually asking here?  Unfortunately, your English is very difficult to understand.  (Are you using an automatic translator?  If you are, it is doing the translation really badly!)

Comment: So like I want to know how I can return to the main method. I didn't write the entire code in my question but in my main method, there's a menu asking the user if they want to add, remove, view order, or check out. And I also have a list of items that show up after choosing "add" or "remove". If I choose "add" and the item that I want to add, the program will go to the "addItems" function and insert my item into the "cart" array. Then, I return the updated cart. When I run this program, after adding an item, the program ends. I want it to go back to the main menu over and over. How??

Comment: Can you paste you logic in the  main method instead of  " blah blah blah" so that everyone can understand your problem. which will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For continuously  taking input use this.

```js
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while(true)
    {
      String input = scanner. nextLine();//take user input
      if(input.equals("add"))
      {
        int cartUpdated[]=addItems( cart,  item,  addNum);
      }
      else if(input.equals("remove"))
      {
        //call remove method
      }
      else if(input.equals("quit"))
      {
        System.exit(0);//exit(0) : Generally used to indicate   successful termination.
      }
    }
    
}
```